# Partial functionality of Addin with Windows Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, windows-installer, vsto, add-in

I have had some trouble with my Excel Addin and the Windows Installer. I tried following the steps as set out in the demo (shown on Pluralsight) on a test project and it works fine.

For my custom addin, I used VS2010 and the addin targets Excel 2007. There are more projects in my solution than only the Addin project and the setup project. After I have run the msi file that I created with the setup project, then if I have a message box in the ThisAddIn_Startup method of the ThisAddin.cs class, then it shows the messagebox, but it does not display the Ribbon tab that I created in the same project. I have tried to see whether any errors show up by creating the VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS and VSTO_LOGALERTS variables, but I don't see any logfiles. After I build the projects and create the msi and setup.exe files, I clean the solution in Visual Studio, and try the installation from the external msi file, since I'm testing this on the development computer for now. Perhaps I should add, that if I run the setup.exe file, I don't even get the messagebox.

My addin is not disabled, and is ticked in the COM-Addins dialog. I have the registry set up for HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Why do I see the messagebox, but not my tab on the Ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there was an exception when the Ribbon loaded, and this is why it did not show. When I cleared that problem, the Ribbon loaded correctly. The exception was not picked up by the debugging though, it just silently malfunctioned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Ribbon XML not the Ribbon designer.
If Ribbon XML then add the following code in to your ThisAddin.cs

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
       return new Ribbon1();
    }
```

Comment: No, I used the Ribbon Designer to create my custom Ribbon. I have the normal Ribbon.cs and Ribbon.Designer.cs classes as part of the Addin project. When I try to use your code above I get an error about trying to implicitly casting Ribbon to Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility, which makes sense.

Comment: In that case check the Control Id property for the ribbon tab, it should be (ControlIdType - Office and OfficeId - TabAddIns) or (ControlIdType - Custom and OfficeId - <anystring>)

Comment: It is "ControlIdType - Office and OfficeId - TabAddIns". It works fine when I haven't cleaned the solution, or do the installation from within Visual Studio. Unfortunately the Ribbon (but not the messagebox) goes missing when it is installed from a Windows installer or even a ClickOnce installation. I have sent it to a friend, to test on his computer, and he experiences the same (although he uses Office 2010).

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood that the ribbon doesnt appear in either cases.

Comment: Does it appear in Word Options => Customize Ribbon tab? If not try using Ribbon XML (random guess, I did had some random issues with Ribbon designer)

Comment: Hm... my custom tab is listed in the options there, but it does not show on the actual Ribbon. It also lists the Developer tab, which I did not create, but it is also not shown on the Ribbon. So the Developer tab and my CustomTab exist, but mysteriously disappear...

Comment: Developer tab is hidden by default, unless you check the Developer it will not appear. Next guess is the file Word.officeUI located in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office is readonly or losing your settings everytime.

Comment: I don't have such a file. Apart from the fact that I assume it should be Excel.officeUI?

Comment: Yes it should be Excel.officeUI for Excel. Check you roaming profile just in case. I guess this file gets rewritten, also check when you enable the addins manually from Developer does it make the your ribbon tab to apper.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with roaming profile? Anyways, I excluded the CustomRibbon.cs (the one not showing) from the project, and added a new TestRibbon.cs with a test group and a test button, and the TestRibbon shows. Then I added another Ribbon object (Ribbon2.cs) and tried to copy the contents of the CustomRibbon.cs to the Ribbon2.cs and likewise for the Designer parts, but then it goes missing. So it must be something in my code I assume. It can't be the setup project, and it seems like it can't be some external file. Or may I be mistaken?

Comment: I created a new Ribbon and excluded the "missing" one from the project. I found that there was an unhandled exception, and that this causes one of the groups (and previoiusly probably the whole Ribbon tab) to disappear. However, now that I catch the exception and handle it better, how can I re-enable that group on the tab? I've created a test group that calls the same method that throws the exception, and that still shows, but is there another solution or should a copy the functionality of the original group (now missing) to the test group?